# How to display a UIButton on top of it's UITableViewCell's text?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, image-clipping

I am having trouble figuring out how to place a UIButton with a custom image above the text in the UITableViewCell that it belongs to. Is there a way to reorder the items outside of the visible storyboard hierarchy?

In the storyboard, I have tried:

1. Setting the button to opaque.
2. Unchecking 'Clip Subviews' in for the cell view.

Nothing I tried works. Below is a picture of how it appears now.

[image: Notice how the text is in front of the button?]

Comment: You can drag the views in the scene list. The lowest down view in the list is the topmost view (in z order), so drag the button below the label.

Comment: The label isn't in the storyboard list.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need the following code to insert your subview above the UILabel.

```
[self.view insertSubview:<#(UIView *)#> aboveSubview:<#(UIView *)#>];
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem with me doing this is that the button is now resized greatly and they are no longer linked to their actions. However, I am starting to think that my images are partially transparent because I can see that where the text intersects the image, the text color changes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed to do:

```
UIButton * button = (* obtain button *)
[button.superview bringSubviewToFront:button];
```